# Navigation component - No Directions class generated

Tags: android, android-studio, navigation, android-architecture-navigation

I have a fragment A where an action is originated to fragment B which have to receive an argument. When I try to set the argument before navigate, 'FragmentADirections' class can't be resolve. 
The fact is, I have a fragment C going to D with an argument to and this work well for these two.

Fragment A class ('EntrainementAction'):

```
    package com.example.androidsportsomveille.Fragments;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.navigation.Navigation;

import com.example.androidsportsomveille.Classes.Entrainement;
import com.example.androidsportsomveille.R;

public class EntrainementAction extends Fragment {

    private Entrainement entrainement;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_entrainement_action, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        this.entrainement = EntrainementActionArgs.fromBundle(getArguments()).getMyEntrainement();

        // Remplis le layout avec les données de l'enrainement
        populateLayout();

        // Aller à la gestion de l'entrainement
        Button btnGestion = view.findViewById(R.id.btnGestionEntrainement);
        btnGestion.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Set de l'argument puis navigation
                EntrainementActionDirections.ActionEntrainementActionToEntrainementGestion action =
                        EntrainementActionDirections.actionEntrainementActionToEntrainementGestion(entrainement);
                Navigation.findNavController(view).navigate(action);
            }
        });
    }

    public void populateLayout() {
        TextView txtNom = getView().findViewById(R.id.txtNomEntrainement);
        txtNom.setText(this.entrainement.getNom());
    }
}
```

Error appear in 'btnGestion.setOnClickListener' where 'EntrainementActionDirections' cannot be resolve. Note that I have other Directions class well generated.

My nav_graph.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/nav_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/entrainementListe">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/entrainementListe"
        android:name="com.example.androidsportsomveille.Fragments.EntrainementListe"
        android:label="fragment_entrainement_liste"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_entrainement_liste" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_entrainementListe_to_entrainementNouveau"
            app:destination="@id/entrainementNouveau" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_entrainementListe_to_entrainementAction"
            app:destination="@id/entrainementAction" />
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/entrainementNouveau"
        android:name="com.example.androidsportsomveille.Fragments.EntrainementNouveau"
        android:label="fragment_entrainement_nouveau"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_entrainement_nouveau" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_entrainementNouveau_to_entrainementGestion"
            app:destination="@id/entrainementGestion" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/entrainementAction"
        android:name="com.example.androidsportsomveille.Fragments.EntrainementAction"
        android:label="fragment_entrainement_action"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_entrainement_action" >
        <argument
            android:name="myEntrainement"
            app:argType="com.example.androidsportsomveille.Classes.Entrainement" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_entrainementAction_to_entrainementGestion"
            app:destination="@id/entrainementGestion" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/entrainementGestion"
        android:name="com.example.androidsportsomveille.Fragments.EntrainementGestion"
        android:label="fragment_entrainement_gestion"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_entrainement_gestion" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_entrainementGestion_to_entrainementAction"
            app:destination="@id/entrainementAction" />
        <argument
            android:name="myEntrainement"
            app:argType="com.example.androidsportsomveille.Classes.Entrainement" />
    </fragment>
</navigation>
```

Fragments 'entrainementAction' and 'entrainementGestion' haven't Directions class generated while 'entrainementListe' and 'entrainementNouveau' have.
All fragment's xml files exists.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After a lunch break, I launched android studio and then my Directions classes are generated. I don't know why I couldn't use them earlier.

Comment: It is because you need to build Application

Comment: Actually, I remember well building the application several times, that's why I asked help here. 
I'm pretty sur there was a cache conflict, I should have unvalidate it but it's too late now ^^

Answer (score 21):

double-check to have this in your app Gradle (at top)

```
plugins {
    id "androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin"
}
```

Comment: only buildscript {} and other plugins {} script blocks are allowed before plugins {} blocks, no other statements are allowed

Answer (score 7):

From: https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started

The recommended way to navigate between destinations is to use the Safe Args Gradle plugin. This plugin generates simple object and builder classes that enable type-safe navigation and argument passing between destinations.

To add Safe Args to your project, include the following classpath in your top level build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    google()
}
dependencies {
    def nav_version = "2.3.5"
    classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:$nav_version"
}
```

}

To generate Java language code suitable for Java or mixed Java and Kotlin modules, add this line to your app or module's build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: "androidx.navigation.safeargs"
```

You must have android.useAndroidX=true in your gradle.properties file as per Migrating to AndroidX.

After you enable Safe Args, the plugin generates code that contains classes and methods for each action you've defined.